# dyld: Symbol not found - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks, starscream

Im getting the following log with crash after adding static framework to my app. 
The project build successfully. but when I run the application. it crashing immediately after launching.

````
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8692616-FADE-4733-9FFB-78C848909E61/Beta.app/Frameworks/MySDK.framework/MySDK
  Expected in: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8692616-FADE-4733-9FFB-78C848909E61/  Beta.app/Frameworks/Starscream.framework/Starscream
 in /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/F8692616-FADE-4733-9FFB-78C848909E61/Beta.app/Frameworks/MySDK.framework/MySDK
(lldb)  ```
````

Comment: Are you using cocoapods and run on iOS 13.3.1 ?

Comment: The framework that I used to add was not a pod. static framework

Comment: Also Im using Cocoapods too for other libraries. Yes running on iOS 13.3.1

Comment: try comment use_framework line in pod file and install  pod again, clean the project and test it